# compare two rows excel with C# OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#

I try to compare the current position with the next position fecmov, but not working, They are always different though they are  not validate

I have this code:

```
string FECMOV;
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName);
        if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xls")  {
                    con1 = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;MaxScanRows=0\"", filePath);
                }
                else if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) == ".xlsx")  {
                    con1 = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;MaxScanRows=0\"", filePath);
                }

                using (OleDbConnection connect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(con1)) {

                    connect.Open();

                    OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connect);

                    using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) {
                        if (dr.HasRows)  {
                            while (dr.Read())  {

                                if (dr.IsDBNull(4))  {
                                    FECMOV = "";
                                }

                                else {
                                    FECMOV = dr[4].ToString().Trim();
                                }
                                 //this validation I try to compare 
                                 // the current position with the next                
                                //position fecmov, but not working, 


                                      if (FECMOV[a] != FECMOV[a + 1])
                                        {
                                             a=a+1
                                         } 
                  //They are always different though they are  not validate
                                  }}}
```

Comment: FECMOV is a string, You are comparing the character at position `a` with the character at position `a+1`. Do you expect your string to be composed of the same character all along?

Comment: Yep  I need compare the first register with second register of the same column...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class DataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        var cols = x.Table.Columns.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(x[i]) != Convert.ToString(y[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        var hashCode = -1;

        var cols = obj.Table.Columns.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            if (hashCode == -1)
            {
                hashCode = obj[i].GetHashCode();
            }
            else
            {
                hashCode = hashCode ^ obj[i].GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer not is a solution for me....... I can not use a datarow, I need to read and compare the same time , the front row with the second row of the same column , in this case the column number 4 I'm using excel.